# Verb or Adjective

Tags: verbs, adjectives, gerunds

Sometimes we use `verb+ing` form I don't know what they are gerunds or adjectives.

Like in this sentence *The car mowed down two people before hitting the tree.*

Comment: You use _gerund_ after _prepositions_ (after, before, without, in spite of, on, etc.).

Comment: Could you please explain what's the logic behind, is it describing continuous action ?

Comment: But 'hitting' is an action here. How this can function as a noun

Comment: _Hitting the tree_ is a verb. You can't say "before to hit the tree". You use gerund after prepositions.

Comment: you said that it function as a noun

Answer (score 1):

The `verb+ing` is used in two ways: as a present participle, and as a gerund.

## Present Participle:

Present participles are formed from verbs. **Present participles are used either as an adjective or when forming continuous tenses.**

Examples:

> - He is **running** towards me. *[run+ing]* *(forming present continuous tense)*
> - The boys are **laughing.** *[laugh+ing]* *(forming present continuous tense)*
> - The **laughing** fish was my favourite of the two. *(used as an adjective modifying "fish")*

## Gerund:

Gerunds **are nouns**—and used as nouns—that are also formed from verbs. The same form, `verb+ing`, is used.

As the user "Student" explained, gerunds are also used after prepositions.

> - **Laughing** is good for heath. *(gerund used as a subject)*

Take your example:

> - The car mowed down two people before hitting the tree.

Here, the subject is "the car." "Hitting" is the gerund which is being used as the object of preposition.

---

[OP's query](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85937/verb-or-adjective/85966?noredirect=1#comment170418_85966):

> I have one more doubt like in these sentences: 1.The laughing fish was my favourite of the two. (used as an adjective modifying "fish") 2. It is a working machine. In both examples 'laughing' and 'working' are present participle used as an adjective?

"laughing" is present participle used as an adjective. Same goes for "working." Note that the machine is in working condition. "Working," a present participle used as an adjective, is modifying the noun, machine.

Example:

> This man is **laughing**.

This means that the person is laughing at the time of speaking. "Laughing" here is present participle which is used as a present participle to form the continuous tense.

> A **laughing** man is a good man. *(just an example, please don't berate me)*

Here, "laughing" is a present participle but used as an adjective which modifies the noun "man."

---

Further Read at [Edufind.com](http://www.edufind.com): [Present Participle](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/present-participle/)

Comment: That means gerund can be an object and subject and they both are also noun?

Comment: @Rocky Yes. Read [here](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/gerund/) to understand more uses of gerund. :) A gerund will always be a noun. Though, the noun can be the subject, object, subject compliment, etc..

Comment: Okay but I can't understand  "If you can put the pronoun "it" after the word "to" and form a meaningful sentence, then the word "to" is a preposition and must be followed by a gerund". where is gerund here "I look forward to it". "I am used to it".

Comment: @Rocky It is not a rule that a gerund will always be preceded by a preposition. Whenever you see a gerund after a preposition, that gerund is the object of the preposition.

Comment: Okay, but could you give any example of  "it" after the word "to"  followed by a gerund. Is this sentence is continuous  'I am looking forward to it'

Comment: @Rocky Are you asking for `preposition + pronoun + Gerund`? I don't think that's possible. Check this out: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/objectofthepreposition.htm

Comment: I have one more doubt like in these sentences:                                        1.The laughing fish was my favourite of the two. (used as an adjective modifying "fish") 2. It is a working machine. In both examples 'laughing' and 'working' are present participle used as an adjective?

Comment: @Rocky Yes. I have edited my answer. Do check it. If you have further queries, contact [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin) or [here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow)